# How get rows from closest table using one to one?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables:

```
Hotels | Countries
country  id name
```

I need to get all notes from **Hotels** , and get `Hotels.country` will be name of country: `Countries.name`

There is function in Hotel model:

```
public function country()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Country', 'country', 'id');
    }
```

In controller I try to get all hotels with related countries:

```
$hotels = Hotel::all();
```

After I try to get country name for each row from `$hotels`:

```
foreach($hotels as $item){

echo $item->country["name"]; // It does not work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'country', 'id');
}
```

After that,

```
@foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {{ $hotel->country->name }}
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use eager loading.

```
$hotels = Hotel::with('country')->get();
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

In order to access the country name, it's a normal object:

```
$hotel->country->first()->name
```

If you want to have a direct function, in your Hotel Model

### Hotel.php

```
public function countryName()
{
    return $this->country->first()->name
}
```

Comment: It works, after  how to get field name from `country`? I mean in loop?

Comment: which loop? please provide all your issues so the community can fully help.

Comment: Now I try to get country name for each row from `$hotels`. I updated question

Comment: It does not work, that what I do:` @foreach ($hotels as $hotel) {{ $hotel->country->name }} `

Comment: But I have object and see there country: `{"id":1,"name":"Thank you! Your submission has been received!","stars":1,"country":{"id":1,"language":1,"name":"\u0410\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0436\u0430\u043d"},"text":"Thank you! Your submission has been received!","city":2,"active":0,"language":0,"address":"Thank you! Your submission has been received!"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118910/discussion-between-putin-and-mina-abadir).

Comment: You call it $item in the for loop, so make it $item->country->name

Comment: I have found scolution. It should be: `{{ $hotel->country()->first()->name}}`. But it look awful

Comment: actually it should be `$hotel->country->first()->name`

Comment: check updated answer, if you do not want this long relation.